# Enable silent push notification in a closed React Native app

Tags: react-native, push-notification, silent-notification

Have a question about silent push notification in React Native app.
In our app we send data about an event in push notification.  I want to use silent push notification to update data in the app that is closed.
Is it possible for the closed app to receive the silent push notification?
How to implement it into the React Native code? In other words, how to transfer the silent notification data into the React Native for the closed app?
Any instructions, documentations, and links will be great to have.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem & i didn't found any package that solves my problem.
Although you can use this package [react-native-gcm-android](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-gcm-push-notification)
(or anything similar) to receive gcm push notifications and handle showing notifications to user(or anything you want to do) by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can check `silent remote push notifications` in https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/trouble-shooting.md. Here it is properly described what is the silent push notification, how handle it in your app, data structure you receive on RN and data structure you need to send from server. Hope this will help